# How can I collapsible the facet search block with checkbox

Tags: search

I need to create a  collapsible facet search block with check-box. Has anyone done this type of functionality. 
I tried the Facet API Collapsible module but this modules provides the link and not the check-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did work on similar functionality, where the client wanted a set of check boxes inside the collapsible Facet Block. 
I found a module [Collapsiblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/collapsiblock) which allows us to have check boxes inside the Facet Block.
This module will most probably help you.

Comment: Thanks Anand for your response.

It is help-full for me.